# How do I display all country list in ComboBox? [JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, iso

```
public void start(final Stage frame) throws Exception {
    String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();
    for (String countrylist : locales) {
        Locale obj = new Locale("", countrylist);
        String[] city = {obj.getDisplayCountry()};
        for (int x = 0; x < city.length; x++) {
            cities = FXCollections.observableArrayList(obj.getDisplayCountry());
            country = new ComboBox<String>(cities);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display the country list using Locale class. However I only manage to display one country in the Combobox when I run the code. I am not sure whether I got the loop wrong or what.

Comment: Let me format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use This code**

```
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

                ObservableList<String> cities = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                ComboBox<String> country = new ComboBox<String>(cities);

                String[] locales1 = Locale.getISOCountries();
                for (String countrylist : locales1) {
                    Locale obj = new Locale("", countrylist);
                    String[] city = { obj.getDisplayCountry() };
                    for (int x = 0; x < city.length; x++) {
                        cities.add(obj.getDisplayCountry());
                    }
                }
                country.setItems(cities);
 }
```

Comment: If you are answearing question then at least use correct naming convention. What does `aaa` class means?? OP posted enough code to solve his problem, then why you are creating example that is not related to provided code?

Answer (score 1):

you are creating a new combo box every loop, try creating it outside the loops and only fill it inside?

Hope that helps.

Greetings,

Gian-Marco

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new `ComboBox` in every iteration, that is why you always get `ComboBox` with single country(last country in list). You can use `Stream` to get all countries.

```
ObservableList<String> countries = Stream.of(Locale.getISOCountries())
        .map(locales -> new Locale("", locales))
        .map(Locale::getDisplayCountry)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(FXCollections::observableArrayList));

ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<>(countries);
```

Answer (score 0):

here you get the list

```
    ComboBox<String> country = new ComboBox<>();
    String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();
    for (String countrylist : locales) {
        Locale obj = new Locale("", countrylist);
        String[] city = {obj.getDisplayCountry()};
        country.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(locales));
    }
```